# Using Roslyn how to enumerate members in a Visual Basic document of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

In order to enumerate members in a C# document you can use Roslyn as follows:

```
var members = SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();
```

What is equivalent for Visual Basic document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the closest equivalent to `MemberDeclarationSyntax` in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax` is [`DeclarationStatementSyntax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualbasic.syntax.declarationstatementsyntax). This means the following code should work:

```
var members = SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<DeclarationStatementSyntax>();
```

Though this will give you more than just member declarations. If you want just members, you will have to filter them out manually. The code for that could look something like:

```
var members = SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().Where(node =>
    node is EnumMemberDeclarationSyntax ||
    node is FieldDeclarationSyntax ||
    node is IncompleteMemberSyntax ||
    node is MethodBaseSyntax || 
    …);
```

Comment: Many thanks. That works. Now I am struggling to determine member Name, StartLine, EndLine.

Comment: @JoginderSNahil If you think my answer actually answered your question, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/130186).

Comment: How do I user the members to determine member’s Name, StartLine, EndLineNumber ?

Comment: @JoginderSNahil You should ask a new question about that.

Comment: I have asked new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120799/using-roslyn-how-to-determine-members-details-in-visual-basic-document