# Using Roslyn, how to enumerate members (Namespaces, classes etc) details in Visual Basic Document?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Using Roslyn, the only mechanism for determining members of Visual Basic document appears to be:

```cs
var members = SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().Where(node =>
      node is ClassStatementSyntax ||
      node is FunctionAggregationSyntax ||
      node is IncompleteMemberSyntax ||
      node is MethodBaseSyntax ||
      node is ModuleStatementSyntax ||
      node is NamespaceStatementSyntax ||
      node is PropertyStatementSyntax ||
      node is SubNewStatementSyntax
    );
```

How do get the member `name`, `StarLineNumber` and `EndLineNumber` of each member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists not only the one way to get it:

1) As you try: I willn't show this way for all of kind member (they count are huge and the logic is the similar), but only a one of them, for example `ClassStatementSyntax`:

- to achive it name just get `ClassStatementSyntax.Identifier.ValueText`
- to get start line you can use `Location` as one of ways:

```cs
var location = Location.Create(SyntaxTree, ClassStatementSyntax.Identifier.Span);
var startLine = location.GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Line;
```

- logic for retrieving the end line looks like a logic to receive the start line but it dependents on the corresponding closing statement (some kind of end statement or self)

2) More useful way – use `SemanticModel` to get a data that you want:
In this way you will need to receive semantic info only for `ClassStatementSyntax`, `ModuleStatementSyntxt` and `NamespaceStatementSyntax`, and all of their members will be received just calling `GetMembers()`:

```cs
...

  SemanticModel semanticModel = // usually it is received from the corresponding compilation
  var typeSyntax = // ClassStatementSyntax, ModuleStatementSyntxt or NamespaceStatementSyntax
  string name = null;
  int startLine;
  int endLine;

  var info = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(typeSyntax);
  if (info.Symbol is INamespaceOrTypeSymbol typeSymbol)
  {
      name = typeSymbol.Name; // retrieve Name
      startLine = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(typeSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].Span).StartLinePosition.Line; //retrieve start line
      endLine = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(typeSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].Span).EndLinePosition.Line; //retrieve end line
      foreach (var item in typeSymbol.GetMembers())
      {
          // do the same logic for retrieving name and lines for all others members without calling GetMembers()
      }
  }
  else if (semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(typeSyntax) is INamespaceOrTypeSymbol typeSymbol2)
  {
      name = typeSymbol2.Name; // retrieve Name
      startLine = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(typeSymbol2.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].Span).StartLinePosition.Line; //retrieve start line
      endLine = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetLineSpan(typeSymbol2.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].Span).EndLinePosition.Line; //retrieve end line

      foreach (var item in typeSymbol2.GetMembers())
      {
          // do the same logic for retrieving name and lines for all others members without calling GetMembers()
      }
  }
```

But attention, when you have a partial declaration your `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` will have a couple items, so you need to filter `SyntaxReference` by your current `SyntaxTree`

Comment: Any idea why the startLine and endLine be the same value?

Comment: @JoginderSNahil, it means that you have a some declaration that may be located fully on the one line, for example `FieldDeclarationSyntax`,`PropertyDeclarationSyntax` (without `Get`, `Set`), `MethodStatementSyntax` (for `MustOverride` method) can be located at the one line and etc., so startLine and endLine will be the same, but the startPosition and endPosition of course will be different.

Comment: I only analysed  Namespace and Class declarations and they are not on the same line. Does the logic works for you?

Comment: @JoginderSNahil, my apologies, I really believed that `ISymbol.Locations` contains the full span of item, not just a start of declaration. I updated answer changed usages of `Locations` at `DeclaringSyntaxReferences`

Comment: Your changes work perfectly. Many thanks for providing the answer in such a detail.

Comment: @JoginderSNahil, is it you downvoted the answer by mistake or someone else? :)

Comment: I had not realised that I have done that! How can I put it right?

Comment: @JoginderSNahil, try to upvote if you can (want), else I don't know a way to revert it and we don't worry about it :)